# My html form is not being redirected after filling form to HelloWorld.java?

Tags: java, html, forms, servlets, intellij-idea

I'm a beginner in JavaEE, i'm using intellij idea as an IDE and i've made a form into html like this:

here is my `Hello.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="HelloWorld" method="POST">
    First name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
    last name: <input type="text" name="last_name">
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now and i've made a servlet file says `HelloWorld.java`:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String docType="<!DOCTYPE html>";

        out.println(docType+
        "<html>" +
                "<head><title>This is just a title man.. ;)</title></head>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<h1>My name is Rajendra Arora</h1>" +
                "<ul>" +
                "<li><b>First name: </b></li>" +
                request.getParameter("first_name")+"<br>"+
                "<li><b>Last name: </b></li>" +
                request.getParameter("last_name")+
                "</ul>" +
                "</body>" +
        "</html>");
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

and here is my `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Now as i run my `HelloWorld.java` it runs successfully but when run it along with form it doesn't run, i mean When i run `Hello.html` it shows form with proper way but when i fill the name after click submit it shows that error message please see my [pic](http://postimg.org/image/uz5k2j1nl/).
and i started my with proper way and it's working, and After running only `HelloWorld.java` when i put into url using `http://localhost:8888/HelloWorld?first_name=Raj&last_name=Arora` it shows name successfully but by default usign `Hello.html` it's showing that error messages... please help

please help!!

Comment: post your html generated code of the form on the browser..

Comment: As you said i did all but not working man :(

Comment: I suppose you are accessing `Hello.html` by `http://localhost:8888/HelloWorld`

Comment: finally i resolved my problem so that's why i'm considering for giving my own answer and finally my program is working thank you all 

here is solution pls see that [pic](http://postimg.org/image/sf0gdvf8p/).

Comment: Give your own answer please

Comment: My reputation isn't suffiecient at this moment so i have to wait for 1 day... that's telling me stupid stackoverflow by the way thanks man ;)

Comment: ok, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified extension to helloworld file. It should be helloworld.java. Also remove semicolon ";" from title tag. You are getting error, "filenotfound" just because you have not given extension to helloworld